# django template system returning same id for different posts

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms, ajaxform

shown below is template of blog.when user likes a post,ajax will call a corresponding view function to do job.For every post,it will have a unique id which i use here for reference.Problem is if i like anypost,the like is going to recently uploaded post.I don't know much about ajax..Please help me.Thank you.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>blog page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1><a href='{% url "blog:blogpostdetails" post.id %}'>{{ post.post_title }}</h1>
            <p>loc: <a href='#'>{{ post.post_location }}</a></p>
            <p>{{ post.post_content|truncatewords:7 }}</p>
            <p>posted on {{ post.post_timestamp }}</p>
            <p>posted by <a href='{% url "index:userprofile" post.post_id.username %}'>{{ post.post_id }}</a></p>
            <form method='POST' id='something'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type='hidden' id='postid'  name='postid' data-id='{{post.id}}'>
                <input type='submit' value='like this post'>
            </form>
            <p>total like {{ post.likes }}</p>
            <p>-------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class='tooltip'><h3><a href="{% url 'blog:blogpost' %}">new post</a></h3></div>
    </body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
.tooltip {
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
top:0px;
right:0px;
left:auto;
}
</style>
{% block javascript %}
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).on('submit','#something',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($('#postid').attr('data-id'))
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url "blog:blogpostlike" %}',
            data:{
                postid:$('#postid').attr('data-id'),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(){
                alert('you liked post');
            }
        });
    });
    
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try using class instead of id for the input

Comment: You shouldn’t have multiple elements with the same id in your html, it should be a unique attribute and will cause issues when you use it as a selector

Comment: yeah of course..  i used different id for different html tags right @lain Shelvington